# WPF apps crash after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: wpf, windows-10

I did an in-place upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 7 and now all the WPF apps crash at start-up (GPF crashes).  These apps include ArcGIS Pro, Visual Studio, and Microsoft Power BI.  Nothing obvious is jumping out as to why.  Has anyone else experienced this or have any ideas as to why this is occurring?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lexli/2009/08/23/when-the-applicationprogram-crashes-on-windows/ You need to do some initial data collection.

Comment: create crash dump and analyze it with windbg